# Is it possible to call a function to execute a MySQL command while using OpenCVs VideoStream in python?

Tags: python, mysql, opencv, flask

I have a web app (using flask and python) that can read a QR code from a live video stream (using opencv). Is it possible to save the data that has been read to my MySQL database without stopping the stream? Every time I try to call the function to save the data, the stream hangs, giving me a NoneType error. I tried calling the same function outside the stream and it works.

In my model.py, I have this function. :

```
def saveAttendance(qr_code):
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE qr_code = %s', [qr_code])
    user_record = cursor.fetchone()
    user_id = user_record['user_id']
    name = user_record['first_name'] + " " + user_record['last_name']
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO attendance VALUES (NULL, %s, NOW(), NOW())', [user_id])
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return name
```

in my views.py, I have this:

```
@views.route('/MaskandQRCodeDetection')
def mask():
    return render_template('MaskandQRCodeDetection.html', username=session['username'])
   
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        data = camera.get_frame()
        frame = data[0]
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


@views.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

And in my camera.py, I have this:

```
class VideoCamera(object):

    # initialize the video stream
def __init__(self):
    self.stream = VideoStream(src=0).start()

def __del__(self):
    self.stream.stop()

def get_frame(self):
 .
 . 
 . 
 .
 #And this part reads the qr code:

for barcode in decode(frame):
    global prev, myOutput, myData
    myData = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
     
    #I saved all the QR code in my database to qr_list
    if myData in qr_list:

        # check if mask is detected and if the qr_code is not a duplicate
        if label == 'Mask' and prev != myData:
            # set myOutput with the name of the detected user
            #This is where I have the problem
            myOutput = saveAttendance(myData)

        myColor = (0, 255, 0)
        # update previous qr_code with the current qr_code
        prev = myData

    else:
        myOutput = 'Not recognized'
        myColor = (0, 0, 255)
```

It gives me the following error when I call the function inside the videostream

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 506, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\base_response.py", line 45, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "C:\AI\website\views.py", line 78, in gen
    data = camera.get_frame()
  File "C:\AI\website\camera.py", line 157, in get_frame
    myOutput = saveAttendance(myData)
  File "C:\AI\website\model.py", line 117, in saveAttendance
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Thank you so much. Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating an app context inside the model.py function. It turned out that for some reason mysql.connection is returning none.

```
def saveAttendance(qr_code):
    with app.app_context():
      .
      .
      .
```